# Access VBA bound form filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access form with several fields that are bound to a query based on the record source.  There is also a textbox with a button.  When the form loads ideally I want all the fields to be empty and then when you put a value in the textbox and hit the button the query is run with a filter on the value in the textbox.  This is done using an embedded macro that runs a Refresh command.

I have tried several things.  When I don't use filter on load, the form just shows a blank page.

When I use filter on load, a popup appears, but I have to input the query search value twice or more in the popup.  After the query is run based on the popup value provided, the form is properly bound.  But when I put a value in the textbox and click the button, the popup comes up again instead of the query executing with the value in the textbox and the page refreshing so the controls can be rebound with the new values.

How can I implement this?

Form
[image]

**qryXYZ**

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM Table WHERE
(((Table.field4)=[Forms]![frmSearchForm]![SearchField]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar a while back. Don't have a recordsource in the form on open, but keep the control source of the controls. Use the "Search" button click event to set the recordsource of the form:

```
me.Form.Recordsource = "SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM Table WHERE field4 = '" & me.SearchField & "'"
```

If you wanted to get rid of the #Name?, to make it look better, you can always remove the Control Source until you have clicked the search button.

Me.**txtField**.ControlSource = "field1"